# what is the "bad" or "problem" of being able to accessing an object's field like the example here

Tags: java

I was reading this example from a book:

```
 class BasicCounter implements Counting {
 int currentValue = 0;
 void increment() {
 this.currentValue = this.currentValue + 1;
 }
 int getValue() {
 return this.currentValue;
 }
```

then it says it is "rude" that someone is able to do the following:

```
BasicCounter anotherCounter = new BasicCounter();
anotherCounter.currentValue = anotherCounter.currentValue + 1;
```

But on the other hand, this way of doing the above is considered "good" (are they same operations exactly?):

```
anotherCounter.increment();
```

And then it says if we do this:

```
class BasicCounter {
private int currentValue = 0; /// make the field "currentValue" be private
 void increment ...
}
```

then it would prevent the "rude"(the above) from happening. Could someone explains why it is "rude" to be able to modify the field like above? instead of just calling the method of the object using anotherCounter.increment() in this specific example.

Also when it says "By making currentValue private to class BasicCounter, only the instance of BasicCounter itself can access the currentValue field. Now, this rudeness on the part of the calling
object would simply be impossible". So does it mean the following two lines of code here would not work? (or actually it still works?  I think it still works because we just make a new instance of the BasicCounter class right? so it is still working even if we declare "currentValue" private):

```
BasicCounter anotherCounter = new BasicCounter();
anotherCounter.currentValue = anotherCounter.currentValue + 1;
```

So these two lines of code still work even if the variable "currentValue" is declared private, right?  If these two lines of codes still work as original (in the "rude" part) ,then may I know what does declaring "private" do actually in this example the author is talking about?

It is on Page 266 to 268 on the pdf (from 254 to 256 on the book) here:
https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/cs/csse120-2004-2005-3-spring-backup/Resources/Reading/Interactive%20Programming%20in%20Java/Interactive%20Programming%20in%20Java.pdf

thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. It is e.g. a duplicate of [Is it bad practice to use public fields?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields) and *its* duplicates.

Comment: in java, private and default are different. private variable is only accessible within the class, while default variable is accessible within the same package.

Comment: The words you are looking for are "abstraction boundaries" and "reducing coupling".

Comment: In your specific example: if you expose the method `increment()` I can only increment your private field one by one so for example you can process each increment, or you can forbid me if I got into a value that you don't like; instead, if you expose the field directly, I may do whatever I want with it (resetting it to zero, make it negative etc.) causing potentially unexpected behaviors on your class that you don't want me to possibly cause.

Comment: Like @MatteoNNZ said: prevent other classes from setting invalid states. The rest of the reasons is more aesthetic, but still valuable.

Comment: @JayC667 - If your codebase is large (or your co-workers are ill-disciplined) abstraction becomes essential to understanding and maintaining your code.  It is not just aesthetics.  Or to put is another, an experienced software engineer's sense of what "looks good" is *typically* based on his / her previous experiences with trying to figure out what is going on in large code bases.  It looks good because it doesn't show the characteristics of code that is hard to maintain.  But there are still ["real programmers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Programmers_Don%27t_Use_Pascal) out there ...

Comment: @StephenC well, but for real abstraction you'd need to use interfaces/inheritance or dependency injection or any other high-level trick. You talk of neither, and only calling a method directly instead of accessing the variable is - when it comes to "reducing coupling" - only aesthetic. Or let's say, homeopathic, because that has no influence on the actual problem.

Comment: Spoken like a real programmer :-).  My point is that style is not simply about aesthetics.  If it was, managers wouldn't allow programmers to waste their time with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is one thing, and what you SHOULD do is another thing.

In the Object Oriented paradigm, there're things like responsability and encapsulation. So, if BasicCounter is the class responsable of counting something, only BasicCounter should change the currentValue value, so you should encapsulate the currentValue field, and create the methods (in OOP a method is an action that an object can perform) to increment that value.